# How get class from element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

Hello i have set of elements. They have several classes on one element.

```
 <div class="color1 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color11 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color1 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color12 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color2 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color2 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color2 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color2 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color23 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color23 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color3 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color3 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color3 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color3 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="color4 chaire">&nbsp;</div>
```

I want to count how much each **colorX** divs are?

I need structure like:

```
color1 : 2
color2 : 4
color3 : 4
color4 : 1
color11 : 1
color12 : 1
color23 : 2
```

I write code:

```
function countvalues(a) {
    var b = {}, i = a.length, j;

    while( i-- ) {
      j = b[a[i]];
      b[a[i]] = j ? j+1 : 1;
    }
    return b;
}

var coalition = new Array();    
var elements = $(".chaire").not(".notactive");
    elements.each(function () {
       var  class = $(this).attr("class");
       class = class.substring(0, class.indexOf(" "));
       coalition.push(class);
 });

   b = countvalues(coalition);
```

Perhaps there is easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div[class^=color]").size();
```

Comment: Yes i can change elements = $(".chaire").not(".notactive"); with $("div[class^=color]"); But more?

Comment: It may be worth taking a step back on this one and ask if counting classes is really the way to go. Can't imagine why you would want to do this. If you are trying to use the classes to confer information to the page then this is the wrong use of the class element and you may be better using the html5 data- syntax (see http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$('div[class^="color"]').length;
```

Comment: Nice one! Using pure jQuery is definitely the best option.

Comment: But i need count for each colorX that present in <div>